# Possibility of attaching non-spatial files to features in QGIS

Tags: qgis, error, pdf, hyperlink

I try to open a hyperlink from a feature in QGIS using the Windows options.
I managed to make a hyperlink working, by copying in the edit action tab, the Adobe Acrobat path, the field name and the destination field, but it shows error messages. If I close the messages, I can visualise the document.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For Acrobat, the [name-less parameter](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf) is a list of PDF to be opened. You are giving it a first valid name, then a folder name, which is not a valid PDF and triggers the error. Note that adding an endig path separator will lead to another error.

The solution is to remove the folder name (so just leave the path to Acrobat and the field name containing the reference to the PDF).

On a side note, this has nothing to do with QGIS. The error message is from Acrobat and the same behavior occurs when using Windows command line.

Comment: It sometimes work, sometimes don`t. Should I insert the link in the field in some way different? I use to add them with copy as path.